# Resizing canvas to full browser window width and height

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, socket.io

I'm playing around with a node/socket.io Pictionary game. I apologize in advance, I am a designer and not too keen with js.

I'm just trying to re-size the canvas so it will be the entire width and height of a browser window without scaling up the stroke path? Right now, the Javascript sets the canvas to 500px.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// ================================================
//                           canvas drawing section
// ================================================

var canvas = $('#canvas'),
    context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

socket.on('drawCanvas', function(canvasToDraw) {
    if(canvasToDraw) {
        canvas.width(500);
        context.lineJoin = 'round';
        context.lineWidth = 2;

        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery to change the dimensions, and that won't work well with canvas (it will scale the canvas contents too). Set the dimensions directly on the canvas element:

```
canvas[0].width = 500;
// Or:
canvas.get(0).width = 500;
```

To set the canvas to the full window dimensions, try this:

```
canvas[0].width = $(window).width();
canvas[0].height = $(window).height();
```

Comment: So if i understand correctly, your saying insert that to the area that says: `socket.on('drawCanvas', function(canvasToDraw) {
    if(canvasToDraw) {
        canvas.width(500);
        context.lineJoin = 'round';
        context.lineWidth = 2;
` ? I want it to be 100% width and 100% height not 500px. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes. I believe jQuery will try to set style.width, which doesn't work well with canvas.

Comment: @DavidDiliberto But now I think I misunderstood the question, and that you're asking about something different...

Comment: No prob. ;-) all m trying to accomplish is set the canvas to be the width/height of the browser window so users dont have to draw within a 500px canvas. They will have a big space! thanks anyway.

Comment: @DavidDiliberto I edited most of the code out to make your question more focused and useful for other visitors. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas[0].width = $(window).width();
canvas[0].height = $(window).height();
```

worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Use clientWidth and clientHeight property of canvas

```
if (canvas[0].width != canvas[0].clientWidth || canvas[0].height != canvas[0].clientHeight) {
    canvas[0].width = canvas[0].clientWidth;
    canvas[0].height = canvas[0].clientHeight;
}
```

and set the css for canvas width and height to 100%;